# Google Analytics 4 Event parameters?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

When using the dashboard in google analytics real time - whether it's in firebase or just in GA4 - I can keep track of not just the events but also their properties. However, when I want to use the "analysis" tab in GA4 I can no longer search by property. Is there a way to use the dashboard to drill 1 level deeper into the event so I can search by properties instead of just events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to defined custom properties (custom definitions side bar option) before they can be seen in the reports.

Comment: I thought I had done that or do you mean they have to be defined again by going to custom definitions -> custom dimensions - > and adding the properties there as well?

Comment: Yes. events automatically get added to reports but dimensions and metrics need to be added to the definitions section.